# File manager for Linux (Xubuntu) that auto renames on move?

Tags: linux, file-management

I'm on Xubuntu using thunar filemanager, and am looking for a way to either make Thunar auto rename files on move (when I move a file to a directory and a file with the same name already exists), or for an alternative to Thunar that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double Commander for Linux does this. When you are moving a bunch of files and it finds a conflicting name, you can select "other options" and select the auto rename all function.

You can find it in apt. It's not as light as Thunar, tho :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own custom action to rename files however you want. You can use bash and thunar's variables like "%f the path to the first selected file" and "`test -a "destination/%f"`" to rename a file before moving, or copy to a new name.

[image: Thunar edit custom action]

That's what the Edit Action window looks like.

To get the destination folder you'll probably have to enter it somehow. You could use the zenity program to pick a directory using `zenity --file-selection --directory` or any other method you prefer, even a separate action for each destination folder, or store the destination folder in a file and only change it when desired.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-gui-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux for other options.

XFCE has `xfce4-popup-places` and `xfce4-popup-directorymenu` but they're not doing what I'd expect, at least for me right now, they might work better for you.

See [XFCE's help page on Custom Actions](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) for more info.

---

Or, you could always download Thunar's source code and add your own "rename" button to the copy conflict section, it's open source so you can play with it as you wish, but that's a little involved.

Comment: When you move files and files with the same name exist, on the destination I want to be able to easily keep both files. That's all. I don't want another action for the file themselves. I want an extra action when I move them and there's a conflict.

Comment: But both files would have the same name, you can't just keep them both in that directory. Thunar doesn't know what to rename a file to, or which file to rename & which one to keep with the original name, so you have to make your own decisions & either put it in your own custom script/action, or edit Thunar's source code & add some options to the "same name conflict" window. Making a custom action is probably faster & easier, but the source code isn't hard to edit either. Or don't use Thunar to move the files, and use a script/terminal and `cp`/`rsync` instead (they both have `--backup`)

Comment: I know rsync, but I want to do it graphically. double commander does this, when you  have two files with the same name on the destination dir, it allows you to select, "auto rename all files from now on". Understand? So whenever I have this problem it's what I do: change to double commander.

Comment: Check out the XFCE.org [forums](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11300) or [Bugs](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=request) and consider adding a feature request for Thunar, especially consider what the new file should be renamed to, and if it's the original or incoming file to be renamed (as mentioned above). If the maintainers think it's an important feature they might add it, or you could submit source code adding it yourself. Actually, [a similar request from 2014 already exists](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10751). Good luck